# Cómo se dice "I'm looking forward to" en una comunicación más formal

Tags: selección-de-palabras, expresiones, formalidad

Cuando envío un email en español, muchas veces quisiera decir “I’m looking forward to” (ej., visitar Buenos Aires; asistir al congreso; recibir noticias suyas; enterarme de sus planes, etc.). ¿Cómo decirlo en una comunicación más formal que a familia y amigos?

Comment: "Anticipar" suena como el verbo mas apropiado.  Solo que no se si exista un verbo en espanol que expresa anticipar "con ganas".

Answer (score 1):

En España, mi opción sería decir "estoy deseando". En un contexto formal es perfectamente válido, por poner un ejemplo:

> Estoy deseando comenzar a trabajar en su empresa.
>
> Estoy deseando formar parte de vuestro equipo.

No suena ni informal ni demasiado rimbombante.